# Use token tokens in ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I ran into a problem with ANTLR and I wonder if a situation like this is even acceptable in ANTLR. I have prepared a very simplified example below.

```
grammar test;

test
    : statement*
    ;

statement
    : s1
    | s2
    ;

s1
    : 'OK' INT
    ;

s2
    : 'ABC' US_INT
    ;

INT
    : S_INT
    | US_INT
    ;

S_INT
   : [+-] [0-9]+
   ;

US_INT
    : [0-9]+
    ;
```

For `OK 5` everything is ok, but for `ABC 5` I get the following error:

```
line 1:4 mismatched input '5' expecting US_INT
```

I was running the `grun` with the `-tokens` option and I have here `INT` instead of `US_INT`

```
[@1,4:4='5',<INT>,1:4]
```

This made me wonder if such a situation in ANTLR was possible at all. Previously, I tried reordering tokens, moving `US_INT` out of `INT`, fragments and some other things, but it didn't work well. The only change was that `OK 5` stopped working and `ABC 5` started. I would like both of these cases to work without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is quite simple: `5` can match both: `US_INT` (since it contains `US_INT`) and `S_INT` itself. But, as long as `INT` is declared higher than `US_INT`, the lexer is going to resolve `5` as `INT`.

To solve it, I'd suggest you moving `INT` from lexer tokens to parser rules, like this:

```
grammar test;

test
    : statement*
    ;

statement
    : s1
    | s2
    ;

s1
    : 'OK' int_stmt
    ;

s2
    : 'ABC' US_INT
    ;
    
int_stmt
    : S_INT | US_INT
    ;

S_INT
   : [+-] [0-9]+
   ;

US_INT
    : [0-9]+
    ;
```

Comment: Yes, and reordering makes another example not working. So it seems to be a reasonable solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape, in this case, from the priorities of the lexing, you can use this ABNF parser grammar in Tunnel Grammar Studio, which does not have this issue at all:

```
test         = *statement
statement    = s-ok / s-abc
s-ok         = "OK" 1*ws int
s-abc        = "ABC" 1*ws unsigned-int
int          = signed-int / unsigned-int
signed-int   = ('+' / '-') unsigned-int 
unsigned-int = 1*('0'-'9')
ws           = %x20 / %x9 / %xA / %xD
```

This is the case of case-insensitive matching, as defined in ABNF (RFC 5234). You can also define explicitly the case sensitive or insensitive matching per string as `%s"ABC"` or `%i"ABC"` respectively (RFC 7405). When you start to have more statements, some strings will start to overlap, then you can make yourself keywords in the lexer grammar:

```
keyword      = %s"OK" / %s"OK2"
```

and in the parser grammar do:

```
s-ok         = {keyword, %s"OK"} 1*ws int 
s-ok-2       = {keyword, %s"OK2"} 1*ws int 1*ws int 
s-ok-any     = {keyword} 1*ws int *(ws 0*1 int)
```

Note that the last rule, will allow you to have any white space in between the integers and any keyword will match.

*I develop Tunnel Grammar Studio. The grammar is quite simple, so the demo may be enough for you.